# c# - Textbox date value shows as 01/01/1900

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a textbox as per below that is meant to capture the date:

```
<input name="datereceived" type="date" class="FormDateValues" id="datereceived"  value="" runat="server" />
```

However, when I try and retreive the value in the code behind, I get a value of 01/01/1900.

```
DateTime InvoiceDate = DateTime.Parse(datereceived.Value);
```

Can someone please tell me why is this returning a  blank date?

Thanks

Comment: Depending on where you are getting it and how, there could be various reasons. Please post more portions of code. Specially if possible the full method for page_load

Comment: '01/01/1900` is the default value for `DateTime` - that means it was never set to a value.  What is the value in `datereceived.Value`?

Comment: @Tim I think 01/01/0001 is the default DateTime value; at least that's what you get if you print the output of: `DateTime mytime = new DateTime();`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any format for your `datereceived` variable? If so, you can try this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(datereceived.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can specify the exact format of your date via the `MM/dd/yyyy` format specifiers, also, try to look at other possible parsing technique using `TryParseExact()` to avoid exceptions.

Comment: I think there is something in the way it recognises the date. When I ran this, it gave me the following error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Then there is a possiblity that the format is not clearly specified. Would you give us an idea how you enter the date? In what format it is?

Comment: by setting the input type to date, it gives me an automatic date picker in the input box. I choose the date from the date picker.

Comment: You have mentioned that it is in European Format on your other comments. Have you tried "`dd/MM/yyyy`" or "`dd/MMMM/yyyy`"? Place it inside the `ParseExact()`, one more thing is that the `Culture` affects it so try to use the `CultureInfo`.

Comment: I changed it to dd/MM/yyyy and I still get the same error message. My code is now DateTime InvoiceDate = DateTime.ParseExact(datereceived.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: You can try to debug the value of `datereceived.Value` check what value is passed before parsing it. This can help us identify the exact value that is being passed by your form.

Comment: So this code fires up on button click. If I get to output datereceived.Value, it gives me 1/01/1900 12:00:00 AM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85049/discussion-between-joel-legaspi-enriquez-and-saj).

Answer (score 0):

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime error will occur due to following reason :

***1. If input text/ value is empty:***
 If value is empty in input field then your conversion from null to date  time will cause this.

***2.If input text/value is in different format that yo want to going to convert.***
     Let suppose your input field is in "dd-MM-yyyy" and you are Parse it to     "dd/MM/yyyy" then it will be through error.

So please check your format and convert it in other ways.

May this help you to figure out your error.